# Medium to large file uploads with progress updates in AspNet Core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

By medium to large I mean anything from 10mb -> 200mb (sound files if that is important)

basically I want to make an API that does some spectral analysis on the file itself, this would require a file upload. But for UI/UX reasons it would be nice to have a progress bar for the upload process. What are the common architectures for achieving this interaction.

The client application uploading the file will be a javascript client (reactjs/redux) and the API is written in ASP.NET Core. I have seen some examples which use websockets to update the client on progress, and other examples where the client polls for status updates given a resource url to query the status. Are there any best practices (or the "modern way of doing this") for doing such a thing that I should know of? TIA

Comment: Progression for the upload or for the spectral analysis?

Comment: For the upload. I have already written a PoC that does spectral analysis and gives back a [0-100]% progress, this is all serverside. I just am not sure about how to do the upload progress. In reality this will be a 2 phase progress bar (phase 1 is upload phase 2 is analysis) but I only am not sure how this upload progress will be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you just need to save progress status while reading the input stream in your controller to some variable (session-specific variable, because there might be a few file uploading sessions at the same time) and then get this status from the client-side by ajax requests (or signalr).

You could take a look at this example: https://github.com/DmitrySikorsky/AspNetCoreUploadingProgress

I have tried 11 MB files with no problems. There is line

```
await Task.Delay(10); // It is only to make the process slower
```

there, don't forget to remove it in the real solution.

In this sample files are loaded by the ajax, so I didn't try really large files, but you can use iframe solution from this sample:
https://github.com/DmitrySikorsky/AspNetCoreFileUploading

The other part will be almost the same.

Hope this helps you. Feel free to ask if have any additional questions.

Comment: Thanks a load, I will definitely have a look at this later today

Comment: A big problem there is the progress is reported on the server, and in a single controller action. This gives no means to see progress on the client, where it is needed.

Comment: @ProfK have you looked at the demo? To does show progress on client side. Client side asks server side to get current progress.